# Docker: volume under bind mount?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's what I've got:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php.docker
    links:
      - mariadb
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: webpack_assets
        target: /srv/myproject/.webpack
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        target: /srv/myproject/storage
        consistency: delegated
      - type: tmpfs
        target: /srv/myproject/bootstrap/cache
        consistency: delegated
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /srv/myproject
        read_only: true
        consistency: cached
    working_dir: '/srv/myproject'
  webpack:
    image: node:lts
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: webpack_assets
        target: /srv/myproject/.webpack
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /srv/myproject
        read_only: true
        consistency: cached
    working_dir: '/srv/myproject'
    command: sh -c 'yarn && exec node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server'
volumes:
  webpack_assets:
```

`webpack` needs read-only access to my project files and it needs to write a special file `webpack-assets.json` which I've moved under a `.webpack` directory because I don't think you can mount a single file.

`php` needs read-only access to this generated file. I would have liked to make it a `tmpfs` volume but apparently those can't be shared?? The host system doesn't need access to this file.

The problem is I get this error when I try to try to mount the volumes this way:

```
ERROR: for myproject_webpack_1  Cannot start service webpack: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/myproject_webpack_assets/_data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc6896fa1823fbb96963b5afd02ac877b6210ed25712be697c226dc1d1943762/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc6896fa1823fbb96963b5afd02ac877b6210ed25712be697c226dc1d1943762/merged/srv/myproject/.webpack\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc6896fa1823fbb96963b5afd02ac877b6210ed25712be697cRecreating myproject_php_1     ... error

ERROR: for myproject_php_1  Cannot start service php: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/myproject_webpack_assets/_data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee4f18947f74ba66fa17775e1b32447e9536609ad527699f3de74ec101d32915/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee4f18947f74ba66fa17775e1b32447e9536609ad527699f3de74ec101d32915/merged/srv/myproject/.webpack\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee4f18947f74ba66fa17775e1b32447e9536609ad527699f3de74ec101d32915/merged/srv/myproject/.webpack: read-only file system\\\"\"": unknown

ERROR: for webpack  Cannot start service webpack: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/myproject_webpack_assets/_data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc6896fa1823fbb96963b5afd02ac877b6210ed25712be697c226dc1d1943762/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc6896fa1823fbb96963b5afd02ac877b6210ed25712be697c226dc1d1943762/merged/srv/myproject/.webpack\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/bc6896fa1823fbb96963b5afd02ac877b6210ed25712be697c226dc1d1943762/merged/srv/myproject/.webpack: read-only file system\\\"\"": unknown

ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/myproject_webpack_assets/_data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee4f18947f74ba66fa17775e1b32447e9536609ad527699f3de74ec101d32915/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee4f18947f74ba66fa17775e1b32447e9536609ad527699f3de74ec101d32915/merged/srv/myproject/.webpack\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee4f18947f74ba66fa17775e1b32447e9536609ad527699f3de74ec101d32915/merged/srv/myproject/.webpack: read-only file system\\\"\"": unknown
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: If I was building this, I'd use a multi-stage build to run webpack at compile time, and then `COPY` the built Javascript artifacts into my runtime image; I wouldn't have a container just to run webpack and wouldn't have most of these volumes at all.  In your environment, can you delete all of the read-only volumes, and have them run the code out of a Docker image instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze I should clarify, this is for development. For prod I'll build and COPY them in, but that's a problem for another day.